# Need Windows to show OS on dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: drive

I support a group of engineers who use dual boot systems with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, each on a separate SSD.  With everyone working from home, if an engineer needs Ubuntu re-installe, they will need to do it themselves.  The problem is, that to do this, the person will need to determine which SSD to re-install Ubuntu upon.  What I need is a way to tell, from Windows, which OS is on which SSD.  I have tried:

- diskpart
- wmic
- PowerShell
- System Information

I have found ways to list the SSD and its size, but none of them shows me the OS.  In Linux I know several commands to get this information very easily, but Windows has me stumped.  Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Maybe one of these solutions could help you: https://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, unfortunately, my company requires any new apps to be installed by an administrator.  I could remotely login to their systems and install it, but I would prefer something they can to themselves..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem using PowerShell.  I used the following command to reveal the systems disk for Windows:

*Get-Disk | Where-Object IsSystem -eq $True | fl*

[Output of above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmxV0.png)

Note both the model number and the first 3 digits of the AllocatedSize.  You do not want to install upon the disk with this information.

When installing Ubuntu and are presented with a choice for which disk to install upon, you now know which one **not** to use. So, you can safely install on the other SSD or disk.